# Return document/collection as object using AngularFireStore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm editing the question to make it more clear :

Using this code will return a Promise, very useful in some case. Service.ts :

```js
async getElement(id: string): Promise<AngularFirestoreDocument<Element>> {
   return this.firestore.doc<Element>(`/element/${id}`);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to return it as an object so it not linked with firebase anymore.

Here is my page.ts

```js
async ngOnInit() {
   this.elementId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   this.elementService.getElement(this.elementId).then(element$ => {
      this.element= element$.valueChanges();
   });
}
```

Any ideas on how to do it ?

I want to be able to do (off-line) operations like

```js
this.element.name = 'New name';
```

and

```js
{{element.name}}
```

I also have the same question for collections.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire)

On `document.service.ts`

```js
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

addDocument(document: DocumentInterface): Observable<any> {
  this.documentCollection = this.firestore.collection(`documents/`);
  return from(this.documentCollection.add(document));
}
```

To use it just inject `documentService` service.

```js
constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
}

createDocument(document: DocumentInterface) {
  this.documentService.addDocument(document).subscribe(() => console.log('Success'), () => console.log('error'))
}
```

[More info on docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#using-angularfirestorecollection)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help, I tried your code but I couldn't make it work. I edited the question so it's more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly you want to get a document, break the connection with the firebase and use it as a simple javascript object. In this case your document fetching flow should look as follows:

```js
this.firestore.doc('path/to/doc').get().toPromise().then(res => {
  this.doc = res.data();
});
```

For collections the implementation is pretty similar

```js
this.firestore.collection('/path/to/collection').get().toPromise().then(res => {
  this.collection = res.docs.map(d => d.data());
});
```

In this case, you're getting a simple javascript object as `this.doc` and array in `this.collection` which you can use as you want. However, none of your changes will affect firebase entities in the cloud directly. You'll need to create separate methods for this.

Please, let me know if I understood you correctly and my answer helps or you have some questions remaining.

Comment: @Max, did you have a chance to check my answer? Does it work for you or some additional info required?

Comment: Hello, sorry for delayed, I was afk. Yes, this is the correct way to do it. I use this way to store the doc data into my service. Unfortunately I'm also looking for a way to use this data in my page. For example how to use 'this.docservice.doc' as an angular thing, like {{ doc.name }}. Maybe I need to subscribe to it, I don't really know. Do you have an answer ? Forgive my bad english, thank you.

Comment: You can inject your service into a component via `public` access modifier and then render in HTML directly object from service i.e. {{ myService.doc }}

Answer (score 0):

`valueChanges` returns and observable so you need to render it using the `async` pipe

```js
{{ (element | async)?.name }}
```

If you want to update it locally, you need to subscribe

```js
this.firestore.doc(`/element/${id}`).valueChanges()
.pipe(
  take(1)
)
.subscribe(doc => {
  this.element = doc;
});
```